# Yandex Allure: link to TMS

Tags: allure

I see, that link to TMS system is available since allure 1.4.4 (https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/pull/429).
We use allure 1.4.5, but I can't find annotation for TMS. It would be cool to add usage description to wiki page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This annotation does not exist yet. This is marked on the following line - https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/blob/f8c6effeba82103bcc24bf424e27627156170d5e/allure-model/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/allure/config/AllureConfig.java#L69 So we support adding TMS ID to XML but don't yet have particular annotation for that because of missing demand. You can create an [issue](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/issues) or provide a pull request to see this implemented soon.

UPD: added @TestCaseId annotation via https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/issues/470